# UITableViewCell Separator disappearing in iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios9

I've created a custom UITableViewCell and i need a bottom line separator for each cell then i put the separator in init method of my custom tableViewCell

This is my TableView code :

```
#import "Telegram_TableViewController.h"
#import "Custom_TableViewCell.h"

@interface Telegram_TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation Telegram_TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];



    self.array =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<200; i++) {

        [self.array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"item %i" ,i]];
    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   }


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [self.array count] ;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    NSString *Identifier = @"CELL";

    Custom_TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier];


    cell = [[Custom_TableViewCell alloc] init];

    UILabel *txt = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    txt.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item " ] ;

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}
```

and my custom TableViewCell code :

```
#import "Custom_TableViewCell.h"

@implementation Custom_TableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
-(id)init
    {

        self = [super init];

        if (self) {

            UIEdgeInsets insets = self.separatorInset;
            self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0,insets.bottom + 6.0, 0.0);
            self.separatorInset = insets;


        }

        return self;
    }
```

There is no error but it doesn't work. How can i fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First share more details of how you created your "UITableViewCell" and `self.separatorInset = insets;` is overriding `self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0,insets.bottom + 6.0, 0.0);` !

Comment: @BabakT i edited the question.

Comment: in my case it happened if I implemented layoutSubviews method of the custom table view cell

Answer (score 0):

Clean init method in `Custom_TableViewCell` and see if this helps.

In `Telegram_TableViewController`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    NSString *Identifier = @"CELL";

    Custom_TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier];


    cell = [[Custom_TableViewCell alloc] init];

    UILabel *txt = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    txt.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item " ] ;

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine];
    [tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor blackColor]];


    return cell;
}
```

And make sure the color of the separator is different than the color of the cell itself.

Comment: I used it As you mentioned, but it doesn't work still.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code in your cell,s .h file

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIView* cellSeperatorView;
```

and in  .m file

```
-(UIView *)cellSeperatorView{
if (!cellSeperatorView) {
    self.cellSeperatorView = [[UIView alloc]    initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self.cellSeperatorView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [self addSubview:self.cellSeperatorView];
}
return cellSeperatorView;
}

-(void)prepareForReuse{

self.cellSeperatorView = nil;

}

-(void)layoutSubviews{
[super layoutSubviews];
[self.cellSeperatorView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 1)];
}
```

and call this method in your tableview class in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)..

```
UITableViewCellClass *cell = (UITableViewCellClass *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCellClass alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
cell.cellSeperatorView.hidden = (indexPath.row == ([self.yourtableViewArray numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]));
```

and in you viewdidload method add this

```
[self.yourtableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

i think this can help you for making separator..

Comment: its a method in which you can create your custom cell's custom separator .. i think it will works for you..

Comment: thanks for the answer , actually i want a simple separator and i don't need a custom separator, i'm trying to handle it with a simple separator, any idea on that?

Answer (score -1):

1. You'd better register in the method `viewDidLoad` when you want to custom cell. `[self.tableView registerClass:[Custom_TableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:Identifier];`
2. What is `cell = [[Custom_TableViewCell alloc] init];`? You are not reusing the cell, but initiate every time. Just do not write this line.
3. The right way to overwrite the init method of tableViewCell to is rewrite `- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier`
4. Now you can see the tableView correctly, but I do not understand a bottom line separator, just write what you want in the method initWithStyle.

Comment: ,As i showed in my code, i'm reusing the cell every time and set its text  in dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method, it should initiate it and i should  declare my custom  tableviewcell in there.

Comment: `Custom_TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier];cell = [[Custom_TableViewCell alloc] init]; ` is same as `Custom_TableViewCell *cell = [[Custom_TableViewCell alloc] init]`. `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier]` is not working.